# CakePHP saving associated issues

Tags: cakephp

So I have 2 Models, `Participant` and `Application`. Wherein `Participant` `hasMany` `Applicaiton`s

I get the data like so:

```
'Participant' => array(
  'full_name' => 'John Doe'
),
'Application' => array(
  'start_date' => '2000-02-11' 
)
```

Whenever I try to do `$this->Participant->saveAll($this->request->data)`, the participant is saved but the `Application` isn't.

But whenever I do, `$this->Participant->Application->saveAll($this->request->data)` it works like a charm.

Whenever I look at the docs, the former is correct.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's passing validation? What are your rules?

Comment: Sorry. It turns out that if you have a `hasMany` relationship, forms should be `$this->Form->input('Application.0.start_date');` even if you're only inserting one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. It turns out that if you have a hasMany relationship, forms should be

`$this->Form->input('Application.0.start_date');`

even if you're only inserting one value

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `Application belongsTo Participant` relationship in the Application model.